# External Javascript File in Sharepoint web part

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am creating a sharepoint web part in which i want to call external javascript file. I have created .js file in following location

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\CustomJScripts

Its giving function not found error when function is called. Is the location of javascript file wrong? 
Following is the code :

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        this.GetType(), 
        this.ID, 
        "_spOriginalFormAction = document.forms[0].action;", 
        true);


       ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
        if (!cs.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("OnMouseOverScript"))
        cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(
            this.GetType(), 
            "OnMouseOverScript", 
            ResolveUrl("/_layouts/CustomJScripts/MyJS.js"));
}

private void GetData(string strSchCode)
{

     Table t = new Table();

     TableRow tr = new TableRow();
     TableCell tc = new TableCell();

     tc.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "return ShowInfo('AA');");
     tr.Controls.Add(tc);
     t.Controls.Add(tr);
     this.Controls.Add(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this javascript to your webpart. In my webpart I'm using this method:

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyScript",
            "<SCRIPT language='javascript' src='~/_layouts/CustomJScripts/MyJS.js'></SCRIPT>", false);
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

Comment: thanks Korin - Marek K. for your quick reply. I have tried your code but its still giving me following error :             Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's an issue with the single quotes? e.g. use double quotes instead of single:

```
tc.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "return ShowInfo(\"AA\");");
```

Comment: thanks bender for youe answer. but this didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [ScriptLink.Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415843.aspx) method and then move your file to 14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033\CustomJScripts.

ScriptLink encapsulates the ClientScriptManager calls along with additional functionality. The name parameter is a relative path, which is why the javascript file needs to be in the 14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ *LCID* directory (where *LCID* is your language number).

Your code would look something like this:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        this.GetType(), 
        this.ID, 
        "_spOriginalFormAction = document.forms[0].action;", 
        true);

    ScriptLink.Register(this.Page, "CustomJScripts/MyJS.js", true);
}
```